# iOS app crashes on launch when only when downloaded from App Store on iOS 12 device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I have an iOS app that works perfectly fine on all devices unless they are using iOS 12. I am not sure what the issue is. I tried downloading the app directly from my laptop, and it worked fine. But, when it is downloaded from the App Store or TestFlight, it crashes on launch.

This is my crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.X.X exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 18.98 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 4.380 (user 4.380, system 0.000), 24% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.411, 8% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b1f6ac4 __msync + 8
1   Realm                           0x0000000101485044 realm::util::msync+ 3117124 (int, void*, unsigned long) + 216
2   Realm                           0x0000000101391078 realm::GroupWriter::commit+ 2117752 (unsigned long) + 264
3   Realm                           0x000000010138bde0 realm::SharedGroup::low_level_commit+ 2096608 (unsigned long long) + 344
4   Realm                           0x000000010138b978 realm::SharedGroup::do_commit+ 2095480 () + 96
5   Realm                           0x000000010138c184 realm::SharedGroup::commit_and_continue_as_read+ 2097540 () + 44
6   Realm                           0x00000001011ceccc realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator::commit_write+ 273612 (realm::Realm&) + 76
7   Realm                           0x00000001012a20f8 realm::Realm::commit_transaction+ 1138936 () + 168
8   Realm                           0x0000000101271628 -[RLMRealm commitWriteTransactionWithoutNotifying:error:] + 288
9   RealmSwift                      0x000000010172826c Realm.write<A>(withoutNotifying:_:) + 115308 (Realm.swift:280)
10  MYAPP                           0x0000000100c7f820 specialized JSONSerializer.serialize(input:) + 178208 (JSONSerializer.swift:30)
11  MYAPP                           0x0000000100cd6fa4 specialized AppDelegate.setUpRealm() + 536484 (AppDelegate.swift:235)
12  MYAPP                           0x0000000100cd5e14 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 531988 (<compiler-generated>:20)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7e400f0 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 412
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7e41854 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3352
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7e46fe0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1540
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b770a2a4 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 776
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b771283c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7709f28 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b770a818 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1064
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7708b64 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 744
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b770882c -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 428
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b770d36c __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b770e150 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b770d224 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 244
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7711f24 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 360
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7e455e8 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7a41e04 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360
28  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018dfd79fc -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 440
29  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018dfe140c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 256
30  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018dfe0c14 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 64
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b0997d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b03e5dc _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
33  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018e012040 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
34  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018e011cdc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 408
35  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018e012294 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
36  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b5ecf1c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
37  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b5ece9c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
38  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b5ec784 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
39  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b5e76c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
40  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b5e6fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
41  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d7e879c GSEventRunModal + 104
42  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b7e48c38 UIApplicationMain + 212
43  MYAPP                           0x0000000100c5a274 main + 25204 (LanguageExampleCell.swift:16)
44  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b0aa8e0 start + 4
```

I serialize a large Realm database the first time the app launches. Is this causing the issue? I have no way to find out because this doesn't happen when I install the app through my computer.

Comment: `8badfood` is a watchdog timer exception.  You must exit `didFinishLaunching` with a view presented as soon as possible.  If you have to load a large amount of data then you should present an initial "loading" view and perform the load, moving to the actual UI once that is complete.  This is to avoid an impression to the user that the app has just "hung"

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks! but why is this only happening on iOS 12 devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695144/react-native-app-unresponsive-on-start-if-debugger-is-not-attached

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe those devices tend to be older/slower and your code triggers the watchdog but doesn't on newer devices.  Regardless I can see `didFinishLaunching` in your stack trace, which indicates that you are performing this work from that function, which you shouldn't.

Comment: @Paulw11 This solved my issue. Thank you! It was taking longer for these older phones to serialize the Realm database, and because it was doing it in the `didFinishLaunching`, it caused it to crash. I changed the location and it fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8badfood` is a watchdog timer exception. You must exit `didFinishLaunching` with a view presented as soon as possible.

If you have to load a large amount of data then you should present an initial "loading" view and perform the load, moving to the actual UI once that is complete.

This is to avoid an impression to the user that the app has just "hung".

The fact that you are only getting the crashes on iOS 12 devices is probably because they are older, slower devices.